# Child element overflows parents border radius on change

Tags: jquery, html, css, crop

Using this plugin: https://github.com/adriengibrat/jQuery-crop

I have an img wrapped by an element that has a border radius to make a circle, on load every thing is fine, but as soon as I drag or zoom the image (with the plugin), it overflows the border radius and shows as a square.

However, if I scroll the page, the border-radius appears again.

What is it that makes the img overflow its parent?

edit: it does not overflow the parents width or height, only the border-radius, until you scroll then it fixes itself

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to apply a border radius to the image as well as the wrapper?

I recently had a similar issue with an image doing the same thing when hovering over a link that wrapped it. I don't know what causes it, the border radius on the image solved it for me.

Comment: That wont help as the image is not always 1:1, and it will be moved around and zoomed inside the wrapper.